# Unable to log in with provided credentials

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I dont have any problem in registering new account (with token) when i tried to login i receive this error. **Unable to log in with provided credentials.** , thanks in advance who ever help me to this question. did i miss something in my code?

this is my serializers.py

```
class RegistrationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    password2               = serializers.CharField(style={'input_type': 'password'}, write_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Account
        fields = ['email', 'username', 'password', 'password2']
        extra_kwargs = {
                'password': {'write_only': True},
        }   


    def save(self):

        account = Account(
                    email=self.validated_data['email'],
                    username=self.validated_data['username']
                )
        password = self.validated_data['password']
        password2 = self.validated_data['password2']
        if password != password2:
            raise serializers.ValidationError({'password': 'Passwords must match.'})
        account.set_password(password)
        account.save()
        return account
```

my views.py

```
@api_view(['POST', ])
def registration_view(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        serializer = RegistrationSerializer(data=request.data)
        data = {}
        if serializer.is_valid():
            account = serializer.save()
            data['response'] = 'successfully registered new user.'
            data['email'] = account.email
            data['username'] = account.username
            token = Token.objects.get(user=account).key
            data['token'] = token
        else:
            data = serializer.errors
        return Response(data)
```

this is my settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    
    .....
    'homepage',
]
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'homepage.Account'
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    )
}
```

this is my urls.py

```
from rest_framework.authtoken.views import obtain_auth_token

app_name='homepage'

urlpatterns = [
  path('api/login/', obtain_auth_token),
  path('api/registration_view/', views.registration_view),
]
```

Comment: can you share your login view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, in your settings you have set default authentication as

```
rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication
```

but in your view you have decorated it with `[SessionAuthentication, BasicAuthentication]` it should be `TokenAuthentication`
It seems you are using drf token authentication, in that case you accually don't need to write a login view, just do

```
from rest_framework.authtoken.views import obtain_auth_token
urlpatterns = [
    path('yourloginurl', obtain_auth_token)
]
```

As you are using custom model where email is a substitute for username, your post request should be

```
{
    "username" : "usermail@mail.com",
    "password": "userpassword"
}
```

Comment: i get rid the """ @authentication_classes([SessionAuthentication, BasicAuthentication]) """ and i get same error

Comment: share your ```urls.py``` and post data.

Comment: and your ```login_view``` seems to be doing nothing, where are you authenticating the users?

Comment: i dont have the login_view,

Comment: please share your post data

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218425/discussion-between-mursalin-and-justin).